# GridView x BaseAdapter and reload in onItemClick

Tags: java, android

Following the [example of GridView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) how I could run a new query of images in the event onItemClick?
I could make a casting of my BaseAdapter in that event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a question here gave me inspiration, hehe ...

```
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            try
            {
                ((myCustomAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).myMethod("new_param");
                ((GridView)v.getParent()).invalidateViews();

            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("onItemClick Excpetion = " + e);
            }
        }
    });
```